# Adding double header to my table Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, header

can you help me with this?

When I do select from my DB, I get following table:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row1 | Row1 | Row1 | Row1 | Row1 | Row1 |
| Row2 | Row2 | Row2 | Row2 | Row2 | Row2 |

But I would like to add another header above the header in table above (example below) where  I would like to group name some columns. Can that be done with PgAdmin?

| Group1 | Group2 | Group3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col5 |
| ----------------------------------------- |  |  |
| Row1 | Row1 | Row1 | Row1 |
| Row2 | Row2 | Row2 | Row2 |

Thanks for your answers.

P.S.: Have not been able to make table right...

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the job of the database, but the job of the client program that formats the query result.